# PHP Send email after send response

Tags: php, html

I have function in my php code:

```
foreach ($myarray as $customer) {
     //doing some code
     $this->sendMail($this->attachedfiles,$customer);
}

$this->response($this->success);
```

This code loop over array and the send email to each one with `attachedfiles` and response to the client in the end.

the problem with this is that it take a lot of time.  so i tried some thing like this:

```
$customer_email = array();
$customer_attachedfiles = array();

foreach ($myarray as $customer) {
     array_push($customer_email, $customer);
     array_push($customer_attachedfiles, $this->attachedfiles);
}

$this->response($this->success);

$indextmp = 0; 
foreach ($customer_email as $customer2) {
     $attachedfiles_tmp = $customer_attachedfiles($indextmp);
     $this->sendMail($attachedfiles_tmp,$customer2);
     $indextmp++;
}
```

And in this format the mail are not sent, Any idea what can be the problem?

Comment: nonetheless, sending emails takes time since your message, of certain size + attachments need to be transported over the network. You could simply send links to attachments instead of sending the attachments into email, this way will be def. faster. Also, if your customers base is large, consider background jobs and queues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Swift Mailer or PHPMailer.
With this libraries you can easily send mails to many e-mails with one action.
http://swiftmailer.org/docs/introduction.html

Comment: the `sendMail` use `PHPMailer`

Comment: with PHPMailer you can add many recipients, like this:
    $mail->addAddress('joe@example.net');
    $mail->addAddress('joe2@example.net');
    etc...